# MessageBox is not Showing up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I dont know what is problem with below code but on running , it is not showing up messagebox with OK button. I have imported app.AlertDialog . Any Idea?

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dlgAlert.setMessage("MSG");
    dlgAlert.setTitle("Title");
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  //dismiss the dialog  
                }});
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
```

Comment: can You show us the complete code? We need to see where do You use this code above....

Comment: I checked your code it showing dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message

        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Hope this code will help you.

Let me know if you need my help for same.

Answer (score 0):

Use android.R.string.ok instead of "OK" and write the code

```
dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
```

once. Good luck!